# How can I strip the element using vbscript and display in message box?

Tags: vbscript

I would like to find the price with 2 year contract and display it in a message box. Sofar I have:

```
Dim MyPage
Dim Price
Set MyPage=CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
MyPage.load("http://www.verizonwireless.com/b2c/store/controller?item=phoneFirst&action=viewPhoneDetail&selectedPhoneId=5723")
Wscript.Sleep 2000
Set Price = MyPage.getElementsByTagName("span")
For Each Elem In Price
   MsgBox(Elem.firstChild.nodeValue) 
Next
```

I understand that I am completely wrong, but I don't even know where to start. I love writing simple programs like this, but I just need help getting started. Any ideas will help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a better version, uses the HTMLFile object

```
Dim HTMLDoc, XML, URL, table
Set HTMLDoc = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
Set XML = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
URL = "http://www.verizonwireless.com/b2c/store/controller?item=phoneFirst&action=viewPhoneDetail&selectedPhoneId=5723"

With XML
  .Open "GET", URL, False
  .Send
  HTMLDoc.Write .responseText
End With

Set spans = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("span")
for each span in spans
  WScript.Echo span.innerHTML
next

'=><SPAN>Set Location</SPAN>
'=>Set Location
'=><SPAN>Submit</SPAN>
'=>Submit
'=>Connect with us
```

Comment: Is it possible to inject a cookie so I may see the page with a location inserted?

Comment: don't know, it is IE so if you get the cookie before by going to the site in IE and your IE setting are fine i guess the cookie is also good for this session

Comment: i mean it is the IE browser that is used for getting the page

Comment: can't make off the response which browser was used but since the control is microsofts and i tested it at work where i only have IE i figured is was only IE, perhaps the default browser is used, my advise in that case is to get the cookie by manually visiting the site with the default browser

Comment: otherwise you'll have to create some javascript that does the cookie fetching and run that in the HTMLFile object, sorry have no example of that

Answer (score 1):

the control you use is for reading XML documents, you need something like this

```
'Create an xmlhttp object, the string depends on the version that is installed 
'on your pc could eg also be "Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.5.0"
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "GET", "http://admin:pasword@10.0.0.2/doc/ppp.htm", False 
xmlhttp.Send
text=xmlhttp.responseText
wscript.echo text
Set xmlhttp = Nothing
```

Run a search in your registry for XMLHTTP to get the right string/version for the identifier.

To get the tag from the html you can use the following

```
text = "blabla <span>this is what i need</span> bla bla<span>second item</span> end"

function getElementsByTagName(sTextToSeachIn, tag)
  answer = ""
  separator = ""
  set oRegExpre = new RegExp
  with oRegExpre
    .IgnoreCase = true
    .Global = true
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "<" & tag & ">(.*?)</" & tag & ">"
  end with
  set oColMatches = oRegExpre.Execute(sTextToSeachIn)
  for each match in oColMatches
    answer = answer & separator & match.subMatches(0)
    separator = "|" 'use something that's not in the spancontents
  next
  if separator <> "" then
    getElementsByTagName = split(answer, separator)
  else
    getElementsByTagName = array()
  end if
end function

for each tag in getElementsByTagName(text, "span")
  wscript.echo tag
next

'=>this is what i need
'=>second item
```

There are better techniques and certainly better languages than vbscript to do this, i suggest to take a look at Ruby which exels in such things.

Comment: Thank you, helps a lot... But I still need some help with manipulating to get one certain tag....

Answer (score -1):

Alex, in response to your comment about getting a cookie and running a javascript in HTMLFile, here a ruby script i found, hopes it helps you at some point, it reads in a page, passes it to the HTLMFile object and in that DOM executes a remote javascript file. It also gives you an idea of the combined power of activeX and Ruby.

```
require "win32ole"

$jsxpath_uri = "http://svn.coderepos.org/share/lang/javascript/javascript-xpath/trunk/release/javascript-xpath-latest-cmp.js"
uri, xpath = "http://gist.github.com/gists", "//div[@class='info']/span/a"

http = WIN32OLE.new('MSXML2.XMLHTTP')
http.Open "GET", uri, false
http.Send
text = http.responseText

dom = WIN32OLE.new("htmlfile")
dom.Write(text)
dom.parentWindow.eval(open($jsxpath_uri){|f| f.read })

items = dom.evaluate(xpath, dom, nil, 7, nil)
len = items.snapshotLength
(0...len).each do |i|
  item = items.snapshotItem(i)
  puts item.innerHTML
end
```

Comment: I'm looking for VB, not ruby.

Comment: look at the "dom.parentWindow.eval" part, this is win32ole so also doable in VB with the HTMLFile Dom

Comment: they use it to teach programming at kids and you can start writing productive scripts real quick, on the other hand it is as powerfull as python and to use these advanced features takes more time of course, look at a few youtube movs and don't let them scare you if it's in OS or Linux, in Windows it's much the same. Tons of sites, eg http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/toc/