# Get values from a website with same ID

Tags: html, vbscript

I'm trying to make a local VBscript to get some values from a webpage. I know that I can use the next code to get a value from a specific element:

`IE.document.GetElementById("id-to-find")`

My problem is that I have the same ID ("hiddencardetailsenrollid") in more than one element so I need to extract all of them. This is the code repeated:

```
carId: <span id="hiddencardetailscarid">10972203</span>,

enrollId: <span id="hiddencardetailsenrollid">11147540</span>.
```

Do you have any suggestion to do this? I thought on a for condition to read all the HTML document but I do not know how to approach it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: Here is it the full screenshot of the sourcecode. As you can see, they have exactly the same labels, but carId and enrollId have different values. I can't copypaste the code, stackoverflow returns me an error (I suppose because "table" tag):

[image]

Comment: An ID in HTML should be unique. In the example you posted, `hiddencardetailscarid` is not the same as `hiddencardetailsenrollid`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I strip the element using vbscript and display in message box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695553/how-can-i-strip-the-element-using-vbscript-and-display-in-message-box)

Comment: This is not my website. I am getting it from an internal website of my current job. The problem is that it seems the website generates a catalog number with same IDs in each car, and each ID has different values ofc. It is not very practise...

Comment: You haven't addressed the fact that in the example you posted, they are not duplicated.  Are you *sure* there are duplicates?

Comment: Yes, of course, check OP now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you *did* have multiple elements with the same ID, which you shouldn't, you could use the [answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695553/how-can-i-strip-the-element-using-vbscript-and-display-in-message-box) (courtesty of [@peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/923315/peter)) and slightly modify it:

```
Dim HTMLDoc, XML, URL, table
Set HTMLDoc = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
Set XML = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
URL = "http://www.verizonwireless.com/b2c/store/controller?item=phoneFirst&action=viewPhoneDetail&selectedPhoneId=5723"

With XML
  .Open "GET", URL, False
  .Send
  HTMLDoc.Write .responseText
End With

Set spans = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("span")
for each span in spans
  WScript.Echo span.innerHTML
next

'=><SPAN>Set Location</SPAN>
'=>Set Location
'=><SPAN>Submit</SPAN>
'=>Submit
```

<strike>You would simply replace `getElementsByTagName` with `GetElementByID` as you mentioned, then loop through the resulting array of objects.</strike> `GetElementByID` probably isn't even capable of returning an array.  But again, **you should not have multiple html elements with the same id**.

Comment: Replied above. It's not my website so I can't do anything with this bad practise :-/.

Comment: I understand that.  Sometimes we work with what we are given :)